# MyBatis. select error

Tags: java, mysql, select, resultset, mybatis

I have a table that contains a lot of data and i'm trying to read it using the FetchSize of MyBatisWhen.

I try to read from the DB

```java
        @Test
        public void testFetchSizeLeggi(){
            ScommessaMapper mapper;
            try {
                SqlSession sessione = ConnectionMySQL.getSession().openSession();

                mapper = sessione.getMapper(ScommessaMapper.class);
                final List<Scommessa> lista = new ArrayList<Scommessa>();
                mapper.leggiScommesse(new ResultHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handleResult(ResultContext context) {
                lista.add((Scommessa) context.getResultObject());
                }

            }); 
                sessione.close();
                assertTrue(lista == null);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                fail();
            }
        }
```

I get the following error :

```
    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
    ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.List
    ### The error may exist in com/surebetfinder/dao/config/ScommessaMapper.xml
    ### The error may involve com.surebetfinder.dao.mapper.ScommessaMapper.leggiScommesse
    ### The error occurred while handling results
    ### SQL: select S.ID_SCOMMESA, S.dt_inserimento, B.nome, T.codice_tipologia,   T.tipologia, Q.id_quota, Q.nome_quota, Q.quota, E.id_evento, E.dt_evento, E.nazione, E.puntata, E.competizione, Sp.sport   from scommessa S , giocata G, evento E, bookmaker B, tipologia_scommessa T, quota Q, sport Sp   where   S.giocata = G.id_giocata and S.evento = E.id_evento and   G.bookmaker = B.id_bookmaker and G.tipologia = T.codice_tipologia and G.id_quota = Q.id_quota   and E.sport = Sp.codice_sport   ORDER BY S.ID_SCOMMESA
    ### Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.List
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:122)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:113)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:122)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:64)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.leggiScommesse(Unknown Source)
        at com.surebetfinder.batch.CreaSurebet.start(CreaSurebet.java:40)
        at com.surebetfinder.batch.TestCreaSurebet.testStartBatch(TestCreaSurebet.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.List
        at com.surebetfinder.dao.access.SimpleObjectFactory.create(SimpleObjectFactory.java:44)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.DefaultResultHandler.<init>(DefaultResultHandler.java:38)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:245)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:160)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:78)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:303)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:134)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:120)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.List
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
        at com.surebetfinder.dao.access.SimpleObjectFactory.create(SimpleObjectFactory.java:42)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        ... 41 more
```

mybatis-config.xml and mapper

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE configuration
      PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
      "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
    <configuration>
        <properties resource="etc/db.properties" />
        <settings>
            <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false" />
            <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
            <setting name="multipleResultSetsEnabled" value="true" />
            <setting name="useColumnLabel" value="true" />
            <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="false" />
            <setting name="autoMappingBehavior" value="NONE" />
            <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="REUSE" />
            <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="25000" />
            <setting name="safeRowBoundsEnabled" value="false" />
            <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="false" />
            <setting name="localCacheScope" value="SESSION" />
        </settings>
        <objectFactory type="com.surebetfinder.dao.access.SimpleObjectFactory" />
        <environments default="development">
            <environment id="development">
                <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
                <dataSource type="POOLED">
                    <property name="driver" value="${driver}" />
                    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
                    <property name="username" value="${user}" />
                    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
                    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="${jdbc.default.auto.commit}" />
                    <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="${pool.maximum.active.connections}" />
                    <property name="poolMaximumIdleConnections" value="${pool.maximum.idle.connections}" />
                    <property name="poolMaximumCheckoutTime" value="${pool.maximum.checkout.time}" />
                    <property name="poolTimeToWait" value="${pool.time.to.wait}" />
                </dataSource>
            </environment>
        </environments>

        <mappers>
            <mapper resource="com/surebetfinder/dao/config/ScommessaMapper.xml" />
        </mappers>
    </configuration>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.surebetfinder.dao.mapper.ScommessaMapper">

        <resultMap id="resultMapClass" type="com.surebetfinder.dao.dto.Scommessa" 
            autoMapping="true">
            <id property="idScommessa" column="id_scommessa" javaType="long" />
            <result property="dtInserimento" column="dt_inserimento" javaType="Date" />
            <result property="giocataBean.bookmakerBean.nome" column="nome" />
            <result property="giocataBean.tipologiaScommessa.codiceTipologia" column="codice_tipologia" />
            <result property="giocataBean.quota.idQuota" column="id_quota" />
            <result property="giocataBean.quota.nomeQuota" column="nome_quota" />           
            <result property="giocataBean.quota.quota" column="quota"/>
            <result property="eventoBean.idEvento" column="id_evento"/>
            <result property="eventoBean.dtEvento" column="dt_evento"/>
            <result property="eventoBean.nazione" column="nazione"/>
            <result property="eventoBean.puntata" column="puntata"/>
            <result property="eventoBean.competizione" column="competizione"/>
            <result property="eventoBean.sportBean.sport" column="sport"/>
            <result property="giocataBean.quota.quota" column="quota"/>

        </resultMap>

        <select id="leggiScommesse"  resultMap="resultMapClass" fetchSize="1000"  resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY">  <!-- fetchSize="1000" resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY" -->
            select S.ID_SCOMMESA, S.dt_inserimento, B.nome, T.codice_tipologia,
            T.tipologia, Q.id_quota, Q.nome_quota, Q.quota, E.id_evento, E.dt_evento, E.nazione, E.puntata, E.competizione, Sp.sport
            from scommessa S , giocata G, evento E, bookmaker B, tipologia_scommessa T, quota Q, sport Sp
            where
            S.giocata = G.id_giocata and S.evento = E.id_evento and
            G.bookmaker = B.id_bookmaker and G.tipologia = T.codice_tipologia and G.id_quota = Q.id_quota
            and E.sport = Sp.codice_sport
            ORDER BY S.ID_SCOMMESA
        </select>

    </mapper>
```

My SimpleObjectFactory :

```java
       public class SimpleObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory {

            public <T> T create(Class<T> type) {
                try {
                    return type.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
            }

            @Override
            public <T> boolean isCollection(Class<T> type) {
                return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T create(Class<T> type, List<Class<?>> constructorArgTypes, List<Object> constructorArgs) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        }
```

Where am I wrong?  My settings MyBatis 3.3.0 MySql e Java 1.8

Thanks

P.S:

```java
public interface ScommessaMapper {

    void inserisciScommessa(Scommessa scommessa);

    long deleteScommesse();

    List<Scommessa> leggiScommesse(ResultHandler handler);

    List<Scommessa> leggiScommesse();


}
```

Comment: Can you post the code the ScommessaMapper interface?

Comment: Code inserted.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `MyBatis` is trying to bind the `leggiScommesse` query to a `selectList` operation but it can't work since the `ResultHandler` is not returning anything. Try returning `void` instead of `List<Scommessa>` in the mapper.

```
public interface ScommessaMapper {

    void inserisciScommessa(Scommessa scommessa);

    long deleteScommesse();

    void leggiScommesse(ResultHandler handler);

    List<Scommessa> leggiScommesse();
}
```